# "docker-machine create" gives connection attempt failed error when run from behind a corporate proxy

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am new to docker and am trying to create a docker host using the `docker-machine create [name]` command on Windows 7 but I always get a connection attempt failed error. 
I added the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` to `Docker Toolbox\start.sh` but that did not help

Also tried :

- `--engine-env HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy IP:port` CLI option for docker-machine create command
- Windows powershell command `$env:HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy IP:port` to set the environment variable at global level

But none of these have resolved the issue.

docker-machine version and the error:

C:\Windows\system32> `docker-machine -v`

> docker-machine.exe version 0.14.0, build 89b8332

C:\Windows\system32> `docker-machine create node-1`

> (node-1) Unable to get the latest Boot2Docker ISO release version: 
>   Get
>   https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest:
>   dial tcp 192.30.253.116:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond.

Comment: Try to set the http_proxy and https_proxy globally at the system level

Comment: Tried that too using Windows powershell command: `$env:HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy IP:port` but this also does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no response to my query above I uninstalled docker toolbox and installed docker on a VM. It is working perfectly now. I have written an article on Medium for all you are trying this for the first time and need help in setting up Docker on Win7 behind a corporate proxy. The article can be found here : https://medium.com/@uvnikgupta/installing-docker-on-win7-pc-79db4217bbae